# Passing parameters to a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass the value from a text box that is generated dynamically and its ids are also generated dynamically. I got the value from that text-box but I don't know how to pass its value as a parameter to a function. Can someone help me out. This is how I tried:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var table;
var invoice_number;
//var c = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    table = jQuery("#table_billing").dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "includes/inc-billing2-db.php?mode=billing_dataTable",
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "aTargets": [2],
            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                return '<input type="text" class="form-control invoice_number" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number_' + a + '" placeholder="Invoice Number" required="required" onblur="getvalue(this)">';
                var x = row[3];
                var y = row[4];

            }
        }, {
            "aTargets": [3],
            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                return '<input type="text" class="form-control date" name="invoice_date" id="invoice_date_' + b + '" placeholder="Invoice Date" required="required">';
            }
        }, {
            "aTargets": [4],
            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                return '<input type="button" class="btn-group btn-default btn-sm save" value="Save" name="save_bill" id="save_bill" onclick="jQuery(this).save(' + row[3] + ', ' + row[4] + ', ' + jQuery("#invoice_number_'+a+'").val() + ');">';
            }
        }],
        "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            a = a + 1;
            b = b + 1;
            //c = c + 1;
        }
    });

    jQuery.fn.save = function(id, contract_invoice_request_id, value) {
        alert(id);
        alert(contract_invoice_request_id);
        alert(value);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/inc-billing-db.php?mode=save_billing",
            data: {
                "contract_id": aData[2],
                "invoice_number": jQuery("#save_bill").val(),
                "invoice_date": jQuery("#invoice_date").val()
            },
            success: function(data, text) {
                jQuery.msgbox_success(data.message);
                jQuery("#billing_" + this.id).closest('tr').remove();
                jQuery("#date_" + this.id).closest('tr').remove();

            }
        });
    }
});

function getvalue(txt) {
    alert(txt.id);
    var tr = $("#" + txt.id).closest('tr');
    alert(tr);
    var data = tr.first().text();
    alert(data);
    data.invoice_number = $("#" + txt.id).val();
}
```

When I did like this I get the error as

> unrecognized expression: #invoice_number_'+ a +')

How can I pass the value?

Comment: `jQuery("#invoice_number_'+a+'")` replaced by jQuery("#invoice_number_"+a) ? You have a typo here

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle or something setup where we can see the code live?

Comment: @thePav I tried using like you said, but I get the value as undefined. How can I get the value?

Comment: @thePav Nope. I don't have.

Comment: Ok, could you please create one here (http://jsfiddle.net) and post the link here so we can see what's going on with your code (HTML and JS)?

Comment: I think the kind of thing you are doing, would be easier in KnockOut js....you can take a look at it if u want

Comment: I cannot connect my db in js fiddle, since frst two columns are filled by the values from the db. @thePav

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error where you call the function

```
onclick="jQuery(this).save(' + row[3] + ', ' + row[4] + ', ' + jQuery("#invoice_number_'+a+'").val() + ');"
```

This should be

```
onclick="jQuery(this).save(row[3], row[4], jQuery('#invoice_number_' + a).val())"
```

Comment: If I use like this, I get the error as row[3] is not defined, row[4] is not defined. @Charlie H

Comment: Yes. You are using `raw` array in this code. So these values are expected.

Comment: But, I get these values, like how I have given above(in the question). So, how can I pass this?

Comment: If you get 'not defined' error in a place you express row[3], this means this particular place cannot see row[3]

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect: `jQuery("#invoice_number_'+a+'").val()`

Try `jQuery("#invoice_number_" + a).val()`

You should then be presented with a value on your `alert(value);`

Comment: I get the value as undefined in the alert.